# PHP: How to echo rows from database?

Tags: php, html, sql

How would I go about echoing out rows from the properties table I've created in my database?

```
<?php
    //CREATE CONNECTION
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    // CHECK THE CONNECTION
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    // CREATE ESTATE AGENTS DATABASE
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS estate_agents";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $dbname= "estate_agents";
        $newConnection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
        //CREATE PROPERTIES TABLE
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS properties (
            property_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            property_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            property_cost VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            property_description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
        )";
        if ( $newConnection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error creating table: " .  $newConnection->error . "</br>";
        } 
    } 
    else {
        echo "estate_agents not functional: " .  $newConnection->error . "</br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you try to do it?

Comment: The first thing you'd need to do is `SELECT` some rows.

Comment: Do you even have rows in your properties table yet?

Comment: Select query missing in ur code ..

Comment: @KurtLeadley I do indeed have some rows in my properties table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    //CREATE CONNECTION
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    // CHECK THE CONNECTION
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    // CREATE ESTATE AGENTS DATABASE
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS estate_agents";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $dbname= "estate_agents";
        $newConnection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
        //CREATE PROPERTIES TABLE
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS properties (
            property_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            property_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            property_cost VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            property_description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
        )";
        if ( $newConnection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
             $query = "SELECT * FROM properties";
             $result = $newConnection->query($query);
                  foreach ($result as $row) {
                    $id = $row['property_id'];
                    $name = $row['property_name'];
                    $cost = $row['property_cost'];
                    $description = $row['property_description'];

                    echo $id;
                  }
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error creating table: " .  $newConnection->error . "</br>";
        } 
    } 
    else {
        echo "estate_agents not functional: " .  $newConnection->error . "</br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks Kurt

Comment: No problem. If you want it to look nice, you can make a table, but make sure your `<table>` tags are outside the foreach loop. The `<tr>` and `<td>` tags should be in the loop though. Happy coding.

Comment: Nice thinking, I've added it to a table. Again, thanks! You've been really helpful  :]

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//CREATE CONNECTION
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// CHECK THE CONNECTION
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$dbname= "estate_agents";
$newConnection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
//CREATE PROPERTIES TABLE
$sql = "SELECT * FROM properties";
$resultSet = $conn->query($sql);
//to get the num rows, you have to mysqli_num_rows     
//you might want to create a function on your db class for num rows and return the count with return mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $rowcount=$conn->numRows($resultSet);
 // plz dont forget to create the function numRows on your class file
```